# Shortcut key is not working on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I have **windows 8.1** . On my system I have configured some **shortcut keys** like **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>** will launch the **Equra application**.

On my windows 8.1 when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> it starts the Equra app.

[image: Shortcut keys]

I also have configured it to run as **maximized**.It works fine on my system.

But when I connected with one client to deploy this application on his **windows 10** system.
This shortcut key issue arrised.I have configured the shortcut key how I did on my pc but it did not
work on his pc .

I dont have windows 10 but next time in future when I will connect with him through anydesk I want to fix it.

Why this shortcut key problem arrised on **windows 10 pc** and how to fix it.

English is not my native language excuse me please **: )**

Comment: Questions: (1) How are you configuring the shortcut keys? (2) What is the language of the Windows 10 computer? (3) Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: @harrymc (1) So to configure the shortcut keys I clicked the icon of the application from desktop and then clicked the properties there I configure the shortcut for key. (2) English united kingdom (3)qwerty . These are the setup of the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 10, the key-combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
was taken over in the UK keyboard.
Here is what I get when I type it using the same keyboard: `é`.

The only solution I can suggest is to install
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
and take over this key combination.
But as the target computer is not yours, this might not be feasible
or is too heavy.

I therefore propose to use another key combination, one that doesn't conflict
with Windows.

Comment: @haarymc thanks as always for your support

Comment: Next time if I get the chance to connect with clients system I will try to use different keys and if still fails will use autohotkey

Answer (score 1):

To launch application with shortcut key on Win10, here is the common way I used:

1.Pin the app to the task bar like Microsoft Edge and so on.

2.You could open the sequenced app in the task bar:12345 by type in Winkey+1/2/3/4…0

**you could customize the sequence by simply drag the icon over the taskbar**

I use winkey+3 to open windows folder shown as below.
[image]

Comment: I am know this trick works on **Ubuntu** glad to know that it can also be used for **Windows**